# Duplicate Page errors with sub domains with same content?

Tags: seo, subdomain, canonical-link, canonicalization

A website I'm working on has sub domains with duplicate content on it.

Example:

florida.example.com/info

california.example.com/info

All have the same content on it and moz and web master tools are throwing crawl errors.

This is a wordpress site. Any ideas on how to stop the crawl errors?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide the crawl error message(s)?

Comment: @JVerstry 

This is the Moz Crawl CSV:


Crawl Issues Report - Duplicate Page Content for Website

URL,Internal Link Count,External Link Count,Page Authority,Linking Root Domain Count

http://www.fl.website.com/what-we-do,0,0,1,0
http://www.ut.website.com/what-we-do,0,0,1,0
http://www.al.website.com/what-we-do,0,0,1,0